# Referencing xml file with dynamic file name

Tags: xml

I need to be able to Reference an xls file name which has a dynamic date at the end that changes.  The file name is made up of 2 parts.  The first part is the static name that doesn't change but the second part which is in date format does change. The format of the file name is as follows

stock_newupdated__16-03-2013_10-41-58.xls

Not sure how to go about this one.

```
$filename = 'staticpartofilename_dynamicdateontheend'


$file_handle = fopen($filename . "xls", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

$sku = $line_of_text[0];
$sql   = "UPDATE mytable SET quantity = 0 WHERE SKU = '" . $sku . "'";  
$result = dbQuery($sql);
}
```

Comment: You need to use this $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  that will give you an output like this 2001-03-10 17:16:18. Split it and replace ':' with '-' in the second part, then concat to your $filename which should contain only the static part and just read / write the file.

Comment: Which language are you working in?